# Exact match in datagrid-filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, datagrid

I've been having problem trying to implement **exact match searching** in a column inside a table using datagrid-filter.

For example:
Under column **Name** if I search "Name 1" the search result would only display only Name 1.
Can anyone teach me how to do it? 
I'd really appreciate your help.

```
        $(function(){
        var rows = [];
        for(var i=1; i<=800; i++){
            var amount = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);
            var price = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);
            rows.push({
                inv: 'Inv No '+i,
                date: $.fn.datebox.defaults.formatter(new Date()),
                name: 'Name '+i,
                amount: amount,
                price: price,
                cost: amount*price,
                note: 'Note '+i
            });
        }
        $('#tt').datagrid({
            view         : scrollview,
            striped      : true,
            pagination   : false,
            pageSize     : 50,
            singleSelect : false,
            autoRowHeight: false,
            remoteFilter : false,
            remoteSort   : true,
            multiSort    : true,
        });
        $('#tt').datagrid('enableFilter', [{
            field:'amount',
            type:'numberbox',
            options:{
                precision:0
            },
            op:['equal','notequal','less','greater']
        }])
        $('#tt').datagrid('loadData', rows);
    });
```

Please refer to this jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/6u2b8pyp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following at the beginning on document ready to avoid case sensitive behavior

```
$.fn.datagrid.defaults.operators = 
            {
                    equal: {
                                text: 'Equal',
                                isMatch: function(source, value){
                                    return source.toLowerCase() == value.toLowerCase();
                                }
                            }
            };
```

Replacing

```
$('#tt').datagrid('enableFilter', [{
                field:'amount',
                type:'numberbox',
                options:{
                    precision:0
                },
                op:['equal','notequal','less','greater']
            }])
```

to

```
$('#tt').datagrid('enableFilter', [{
                field:'amount',
                type:'numberbox',
                options:{
                    precision:0
                },
                op:['equal','notequal','less','greater']
            },{
                field:'name',
                type:'textbox',
                options:{
                    precision:0
                },
                defaultFilterOperator: 'equal'
            }])
```

will do [Your fiddle mod](http://jsfiddle.net/aog5rzec/1/)

Comment: thank you so much for this. I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

According to [the docs](http://www.jeasyui.com/extension/datagrid_filter.php), you can specify a default operator for your filters, like this:

```
$('#tt').datagrid({
    (...)
    defaultFilterOperator: 'equal'
});
```

This uses exact, case-sentitive matches, which may or may not be what you want ("name 1" will not work if the name is "Name 1"). I did not see a case-insensitive option.